# How to get sample hibernate config files for particular versions

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm new to hibernate and have downloaded the `4.3.8 jars` and trying to write my first program.

But where do I find a sample `hibernate.cfg.xml` file for this version.

Is there any reference implementation code available?

Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the sample config files in the downloaded hibernate files, inside the project folder.